# A new "Off-topic because..." option for flags?

Tags: discussion, flagging

This idea popped into my head because of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107258/where-can-i-find-this-book), but it is something that I've thought about before: Don't we need a new option when flagging a question, saying "Off topic because... it is simply not a question about physics, and therefore not appropriate for this forum." or something to the same effect?

I feel questions that would merit this flag occur quite often, and given the current options I always have a hard time deciding what to flag them for... If I'm wrong and there is an established procedure for questions like this, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter which off topic subflag you use, the subflags are just indicators and the option you pick isn't displayed anywhere.

This is different when voting to close (>3k rep), here the reason is displayed, and you also have an option where you can give a custom close reason.

Comment: So I should just pick a random one?! That's... surprising.

Comment: @Danu not ideal, but yeah. When the listed reasons don't apply, usually it's best to consider whether it really is off topic first. If it really is off topic, just pick something random. This is a rather rare case though, the listed reasons are pretty thorough. (except for when the question has nothing whatsoever to do with physics)

Comment: Right... I seem to encounter cases like this fairly often, but maybe not enough to justify a change to the site.

Comment: @Danu true. We can add an extra sub reason if necessary, but it can't be too broad. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Danu If you do just pick a random one, be sure to explain in a comment what you think is wrong with the post, for the benefit of both close-vote reviewers and the OP.